Why I have to GroupBy on second query but not on first?
my second query throws an error I have to use GroupBy c.company and e.employement_type
first query:
      SELECT u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.created_at, c.company, e.name as employement_type,
      (SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM users WHERE tenant_id = $1) AS total 
        FROM users u
        
        LEFT JOIN clients c
        ON c.id = u.company

        LEFT JOIN employement_types e
        ON e.id = u.e_types_id

         WHERE u.tenant_id = $1 ORDER BY id, created_at LIMIT 50

second query which throw an error:
        SELECT u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.created_at, c.company, e.name as employement_type,
        (SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM users WHERE tenant_id = $1) AS total 
          FROM users u 
          LEFT JOIN clients c
          ON c.id = u.company

          LEFT JOIN employement_types e
          ON e.id = u.e_types_id
          
          WHERE u.tenant_id = $1 AND ((u.id, u.created_at) > ($2, $3)) GROUP BY u.id, u.created_at ORDER BY u.id, u.created_at LIMIT 50

So why I have to use it in my second query groupBy and not in the first?

@IłyaBursov its for keyset pagnigation

When you use GROUP BY, all columns in SELECT must either be included in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.
In your query, you're selecting multiple columns (u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.created_at, c.company, e.name), but only grouping by u.id and u.created_at.
You need to add all selected columns in the GROUP BY clause. If you don't want to add all columns to the GROUP BY clause, consider changing your query logic. You can use window functions or subqueries.
